# Is the kinetic energy of an electron always $1.6 \cdot 10^{-19}~\text{J}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, energy, momentum, wave-particle-duality

I was doing the following problem.

For $d$. They bizarrely added an extra step. They calculated the momentum of the electron to find the De Broglie wavelength using the kinetic energy relationship.

However, they assume the kinetic energy of the particle is $1.6 \cdot10^{-19}~\text{J}$. Is this always true? What do they mean by this? It doesn't seem to give me the same momentum as $mv=p$.
[image]

Comment: I think your description of where you're stuck is insufficient.

Comment: Notice the extra factor of 5 in the square root term? The author seems to be using the definition of ${\rm J=C\cdot V}$. The 5 is associated with the voltage (why?) and the 1.6e-19 the charge of the electron.

Comment: This course is on optics, so my background in electricity is very feeble. I do not see why there would be a 5 there. When I calculate the momentum from $mv$, I get a totally different momentum than the momentum they get using the kinetic energy. @KyleKanos

Comment: Wait, so this means that the author actually did some extra steps. He calculated the kinetic energy by 1/2mv^2. Then, converted that eV to find the volts that have accelerated the electron, and comes back to trying to find the momentum. Is that not counter-productive!!!? @KyleKanos

Comment: Anyhow, it does not work, the voltage was 6.41V, not 5V.

Comment: @KyleKanos, could you please clarify?

Comment: Actually, I'm now not entirely sure why 5 V is picked out. Typically, electron microscopes operate in the 50-100 kV regime, so my initial thought of it being related to the focal length is probably incorrect.

Comment: @KyleKanos, mistakes are probable in this document. This is a document prepared by my physics department, not from a peer-reviewed book.

Comment: Even if you wanted to compute kinetic energy another way (not using voltage), the electron is moving at $0.5c$ so you can't just say $K = 1/2 m v^2$ and you need to use the relativistic expression for kinetic energy. Which also means you need to use the relativistic expression for momentum and not just $p = mv$.

Comment: No, the electron moves at 0.05c. This is not relativistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in your title - no, the kinetic energy of an electron is a function of its velocity, same as for any other particle. The *charge* of an electron is always $1.6\cdot 10^{-19}C$, and so the electron will pick up $1.6\cdot 10^{-19}J$ of energy for every Volt of accelerating potential.

The key to answering the question (part d in the problem set) is the calculation of the wavelength of the electron.

The De Broglie wavelength is given by

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p} = \frac{h}{mv}$$

Now the velocity is much less than the speed of light, so we don't need to consider relativistic effects. We know the rest mass of the electron, and we find

$$\lambda = \frac{6.6\cdot 10^{-34}}{9.1\cdot 10^{-31}\cdot 1.5\cdot 10^6}=0.5 nm$$

The other equation used ($p=\sqrt{2mK}$) appears to be using information not given in the question: namely that the kinetic energy of the electron is 5 eV, which is what you get when an electron is accelerated through 5 Volt. That has no visible bearing on the calculation of the wavelength, which can be derived directly from the velocity of the electron.

Incidentally, the momentum-from-energy calculation gives a completely different answer from the momentum-from-velocity equation, and indeed an electron with 5 eV of energy does not have a speed of 1.5E6 m/s... No wonder you were getting confused.

Comment: Ok. Perfect. Just had the final exam and I aced it!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

No. Kinetic energy depends on how much energy you give to an electron.

$Volt = Work$ $done$ / $ unit$ $ test$ $ charge$.

$1.6 * 10 ^ -19 J$ is the amount of work done to accelerate an electron of charge $1.6 *10^-19$ to $1$ $volt$ potential.

Comment: How does this relate to momentum? How come the given speed is equivalent to 5V?

Comment: lambda = planks constant / momentum

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that I must multiply 1.6 x 10^-19 J by 5?

Comment: @yolo123 you can write momentum as mass of electron * velocity of electron. then do the calculation. i think its now clear to you

Comment: Not really. I do not understand where the 5 comes from?

Comment: I think they have used 5 electrons that is not given in the question

Comment: Do u know to what potential the elctrons are accelerated ?

Comment: What I uploaded here is all the information I have about the question.

Comment: u told that voltage is 6.4  from where did u get it ? i got 6.39 which is the potential at which an electron can be ejected with the given velocity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19374/discussion-between-vinayak-and-yolo123).

Answer (score 0):

0.16 aJ is the energy an electron acquires by going through 1 volt.  If it goes through 500,000 volts, it gets an energy almost equal to its mass.

Comment: Put differently - you can express mass in terms of electron volts, and the _rest_ mass of an electron is 511 keV.